# Woocommerce Jumpy Rerendering of Variations/Add to Cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My WooCommerce cart with variations is functioning correctly (can select sizes and add to cart, redirects to cart) but has some display problems.

Whenever you click on a new size, the entire Add to Cart button area reloads and makes the bottom of the page rerender and jump all over the place. I've tried some CSS to keep the display box at a minimum height with no luck.

Any ideas?

Here's a link to a product where you can see the jumpiness: http://theshoeboxrva.com.php53-22.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/shop/carla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woocommerce has (in it's core js files) a slide up and down animation when you change the variation. This triggers the change. You've added this to your style.css

```
.single_variation_wrap {
    display: block !important;
}
```

And woocommerce has a `display:none` property for that div, that changes when you select the variation to `display:block`.

You've overridden their style by forcing the visibility of that element, but the jquery change is happening no matter what.

If you don't mean to upgrade woocommerce you can find this in `add-to-cart-variation.js` files and disable it, but I wouldn't recommend it, since if you upgrade you'll loose those changes.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up - I figured something was going on the JS! I assume that there's no way to include some kind of CSS that forces it to stay open?

Comment: css no, the animation is still happening. You could try to see if you can override the default slide animation that is happening, but I've never tried such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but in case it helps someone this worked for me:

```
.woocommerce-variation.single_variation {
    height: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some misinformation in both provided answers, maybe because of version change, I'm on WooCommerce 3.5.3.

1. It's not `.single_variation_wrap`, but `.woocommerce-variation`
   class getting `display: none` via WooCommerce js. This is important, because Add to cart button is not affected, therefore always visible.
2. Setting height of `.woocommerce-variation.single_variation` can be part of solution, but alone will cause price and stock amount to be placed on top of Add to cart button.

I would perfectly hide Add to cart button when variation isn't selected, but it isn't possible without js. My solution (tested for one variation attribute):

1. Neutralize js element visibility by giving it 0 height (as
   superhenke suggested).
2. Give Add to cart button enough top margin for fixed position.
3. Color background of variation selection button to draw user's
   attention to it.

   .woocommerce-variation.single_variation {
   height: 0;
   }

   .woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart {
   margin-top: 85px;
   }

   .single-product div.product table.variations select {
   background: #f1f1bf;
   }